# what does this mean? stuff = [i.split() for i in row]

Tags: python, csv, list-comprehension, python-3.4

what does this mean in this context?

stuff = [i.split() for i in row]

```
import csv
with open('AB.csv', 'r') as ABfile:
    AB=csv.reader(ABfile,csv.excel)
    for row in AB:
        print(row)
        stuff = [i.split() for i in row]
        print(stuff)
```

this is the output

```
['qqq', 'qqq', 'sd3 3ds', '12/12/2012']
[['qqq'], ['qqq'], ['sd3', '3ds'], ['12/12/2012']]
```

Comment: I think it might be a wise investment of your time to take a lookk at the FAQ entry [How do I format my posts using Markdown or HTML?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a list comprehension. It is building the same list as

```
stuff = []
for i in row:
   stuff.append(i.split())
```

It's just a convenient and pythonic way to build a list.

The `split` method splits a string into a list on whitespace, examples:

```
>>> 'qqq'.split()
['qqq']
>>> 'sd3 3ds'.split()
['sd3', '3ds']
```

For each element in `row`, `split` is called and the resulting list is added to `stuff`. That's why you end up with a list of lists for `stuff`.